Is a Grey paladin of Asmodeus possible?
So, I came up with a concept for an NPC character for pathfinder 1.e that involved a grey paladin with the pact servant trait not just being basically a pseudo hellknight, but being a direct worshiper of Asmodeus not evil so much as misguided.
He would be someone who genuinely believes that a world of absolute law would be best for all even at the expense of personal freedom. They would lash out and rebel, but he believes in time they would see the beauty of order, he became disillusioned with other lawful deities and Asmodeus was the only one who heeded his call, and his relationship would be...complicated especially when it comes to [REDACTED] as he would see it not as a means to control and dominate over others but as an alternative to imprisonment and another way for criminal to pay their debt back to society.
So obviously this guy would be solidly lawful neutral, but mechanically is this legit?

No
The Pact Servant trait allows you to treat Asmodeus as if he were Lawful Neutral, but only for the purpose of your own alignment:

You may treat Asmodeus as if he were a lawful neutral (LN) deity for the purposes of determining your own alignment as a cleric, inquisitor, or other divine spellcaster.

But the Gray Paladin's alignment feature requires your Paladin to fulfill two separate requirements. First, your own alignment has to be either Lawful Good (LG), Lawful Neutral (LN), or Neutral Good (NG). And second, you must follow a LG, LN, NG deity.

Alignment: A gray paladin can be lawful good, lawful neutral, or neutral good, though she must still follow a lawful good, neutral good, or lawful neutral deity.

So, strictly speaking, while you may consider Asmodeus being LN when setting your own alignment, he is not considered a LN deity for the second part of the Gray Paladin's requirement.
One could argue that the word "alignment" in the Pact Servant trait might refer to the "Alignment" class feature of divine casters, but that is a stretch.
However, apart from this most strict interpretation of the rules, the most important rule is to have fun with your friends playing RPGs. And if your table is fine with this little stretch, there really isn't any mechanical/rule problem being a Gray Paladin of Asmodeus. Especially if you consider the fact that Pact Servant allows you to play a (normal) LG Paladin of Asmodeus anyway.

Guess you could call it a bit of a gray area. :v
